# Problems in displaying views in main overview of content types in case of Authenticated user

Tags: 7, views, users

I want to replace the main overview of node with my custom view. So the data on overview page should be displayed with the fields, format, and edit link defined in custom view.

I have created a view and saved it. Then I added the view in Block--> Main content Region. I restricted that block to display in that particular content type only.

I gave permission to Authenticated User to "Edit any content" in that content type. I made all the fields to "Hidden" in Manage Display of that content type.

Now when I want to display the node page then view is displaying fine for Admin user. But when I see that node from Authenticated user log in then old fields and format are displayed. It is displaying the same format as during the default overview.

Please tell me as what I am missing here.

Comment: Hi, what about view permissions?